# T-SQL filter on external join

Tags: t-sql

Using the schema below, write a query which lists the total value of all sales for customers who bought an item from a sales person with the same middle initial as them.  Your query should return a single result.

The `quantity` and `price` columns are both `ints`.
The `Sales - Employee` link is on `EmployeeID - SalesPersonID`.
[image]

Comment: Smells like homework... What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried select sum(s.Quantity * p.Price) as TotalSales
from Sales s
join Products p on s.ProductID = p.ProductID
where s.SalespersonID in (select e.salespersonid from employees e join customers c on e.MiddleName = c.MiddleName) but then I need to add a condition to have only those s.SalespersonID that have a coresponding C.CustomerID in the sales table ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select sum(s.Quantity * p.Price) as TotalSales
from Sales s
join Products p on s.ProductID = p.ProductID
join Customers c on s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
join Empleyees e on s.SalesPersonID = e.EmployeeID
where c.MiddleInitial = e.MiddleInitial
```